# How to sketch a function to which it's Fourier series converges?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

The question asks:

Find the Fourier series of $$f(x)=x \text{, }-1 \lt x \lt 1$$

Then it asks to sketch the function to which the series converges in $ -3 \le x \le 3$.

What exactly is it asking to sketch? Thanks

Is it asking to sketch the periodic extension over the new interval?

Comment: Start off by finding the Fourier Series coefficients.

Comment: I have found the series but I don't understand what it's asking me to sketch

Comment: Extend $f$ periodically to all of $\mathbb{R}$. The Fourier series converges everywhere to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of this extended function.